# Is it possible to automate the Microsoft Hardware Certification Kit?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

Is it possible to automate tasks in the HCK like configuring, connecting to the test machines, selecting available tests, running tests and logging them, all in a single shot?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's definitely possible, but not provided out-of-the-box. You would probably have to build the whole thing yourself which could be a significant dev project. Here is the Development guide:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj124658.aspx

There are some Powershell cmdlets that all start with the noun `HwCert*` which are documented here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296620.aspx

but they look pretty basic and might not do everything you need.

Comment: Thanks for the links, but i am completely new to this. All i have is a Windows server machine with HLK studio installed, could you please give me more information about what are the prerequisites I need? I got to know some snippets in the msdn site, but they use the following dlls:- using Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.ObjectModel;
    using Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.ObjectModel.DBConnection;, which I am not sure where to find in the system.

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me:-

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.ObjectModel;
using Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.ObjectModel.DBConnection;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Options;
using System.Security;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace HLKAutomation
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string sExePath = 
Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    public static string sLogFile = "HLK_Test_Log.txt"; //complete console logged in this text file

    //connct to controller
    public static ProjectManager ConnectToController(string controllerName)
    {
        ProjectManager manager = null;
        try
        {
            manager = new DatabaseProjectManager(controllerName);
            if (manager == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error! Couldnt connect to Controller {0}", controllerName);
                Log("Error! Couldnt connect to Controller " + controllerName);
            }
            else
            {
                Log("Connected to controller " + controllerName);
            }
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception:- {0}", ex.ToString());
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
        return manager;
    }

    //create project
    public static Project CreateProject(ProjectManager manager, string projectName)
    {
        Project project = null;
        try
        {
            if(manager == null)
            {
                Log("Project manager value is null");
                Console.WriteLine("Project manager value is null");
                Console.ReadLine();
                return project;
            }

            //delete project by the name projectname if exist
            foreach (string sProj in manager.GetProjectNames())
            {
                if (sProj == projectName)
                {
                    Log(String.Format("Error! Project {0} already found!", sProj));
                    Log("deleting this project");
                    manager.DeleteProject(sProj);
                    Log("Deleted " + sProj);
                }
            }
            project = manager.CreateProject(projectName);   //creating project
            Log("Created project: " +  projectName);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception {0}", e.ToString());
        }
        return project;
    }

    //create pool
    public static MachinePool CreatePool(ProjectManager manager, string TestPoolName)
    {
        MachinePool testPool = null;
        try
        {
            MachinePool rootPool = manager.GetRootMachinePool();

            //create test pool
            Log("Creating test pool");
            testPool = manager.GetRootMachinePool().GetChildPools().Where(x => x.Name == TestPoolName).FirstOrDefault();
            if (testPool == null)
            {
                Log("Pool:- " + TestPoolName + " not found, creating");
                testPool = manager.GetRootMachinePool().CreateChildPool(TestPoolName);
                Log("Created " + TestPoolName);
            }
            else
                Log("Test pool " + testPool.Name + " already found");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception {0}", e.ToString());
        }

        return testPool;
    }

    //add target machine to test pool
    public static Machine LookForMachine(ProjectManager manager, string TargetName, MachinePool testpool)
    {
        Machine TargetMachine = null;
        try
        {
            bool bFoundInDefault = false;
            bool bFoundInTest = false;

            MachinePool RootPool = manager.GetRootMachinePool();

            //check if machine is in default pool or test pool
            foreach (Machine m in testpool.GetMachines())
            {
                if (m.Name == TargetName)
                {
                    bFoundInTest = true;
                    TargetMachine = m;
                }
            }
            foreach(Machine m in RootPool.DefaultPool.GetMachines())
            {
                if (m.Name == TargetName)
                {
                    bFoundInDefault = true;
                    TargetMachine = m;
                }
            }

            if (bFoundInTest == true)
            {
                Log("Machine already in test pool!");
                return TargetMachine;
            }

            Log("Checking for machine " + TargetName + " in default pool" );
            if (bFoundInDefault == true)
            {
                Log("Machine " + TargetName + " is in default pool");
                Log("Moving to test pool");
                RootPool.DefaultPool.MoveMachineTo(TargetMachine, testpool);
                Log("Moved machine " + TargetMachine.Name +" from default to test pool");
                return TargetMachine;
            }                     
            if(bFoundInDefault == false)
            {
                Log("Warning!!! Machine " + TargetName + " not found in default pool too");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception:-{0}", e.ToString());
        }
        return TargetMachine;
    }

    //make systems readt
    public static void PrepareTargetMachine(Machine machine)
    {
        try
        {
            if(machine == null)
            {
                Log("Machine is N/A");
                return;
            }
            if(machine.Status == MachineStatus.Ready || machine.Status == MachineStatus.Running)
            {
                Log(String.Format("Machine {0} is {1}", machine.Name.ToString(), machine.Status.ToString()));
                return;
            }
            if(machine.Status == MachineStatus.NotReady)
            {
                Log("Making system ready");
                machine.SetMachineStatus(MachineStatus.Ready, -1);
                if (machine.Status == MachineStatus.Ready)
                {
                    Log("Machine is ready");
                    return;
                }
            }
            if(machine.Status == MachineStatus.Initializing)
            {
                Log("Warning Machine is still initializing!!!");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception {0}", e.ToString());
        }

    }

    //list tests
    public static IList<Test> GetTestsSystemLevel(Machine TargetName, MachinePool testPool, Project project)
    {
        IList<Test> Test_List = new List<Test> { };
        try
        {                
            OSPlatform platform = testPool.GetMachines().First().OSPlatform;
            ProductInstance pi = project.CreateProductInstance(project.Name, testPool, platform);      
            TargetData data = pi.FindTargetFromSystem(TargetName);                

            if (data == null)
            {
                Log("Error! No target data found in system " + TargetName.Name);
                Console.ReadLine();
                return Test_List;
            }

            pi.CreateTarget(data);
            IList<Test> tests = project.GetTests();
            if (tests.Count == 0)
            {
                Log("Warning! Test list count is 0");
                Console.ReadLine();
                return Test_List;
            }
            Test_List = tests;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception :- {0}", e.ToString());
        }
        return Test_List;
    }

    //list tests
    public static IList<Test> GetTestsDeviceLevel(Machine TargetName, MachinePool testPool, Project project)
    {
        IList<Test> Test_List = new List<Test> { };
        try
        {
            OSPlatform platform = testPool.GetMachines().First().OSPlatform;
            ProductInstance pi = project.CreateProductInstance(project.Name, testPool, platform);

            //Device Level
            ReadOnlyCollection<TargetData> devices = testPool.GetMachines().First().GetTestTargets();
            TargetData device_tpm = null;
            //Find TPM device
            foreach (TargetData device in devices)
            {
                if (device.Name.Contains("Trusted Platform Module 2.0"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(device.Name);
                    device_tpm = device;
                }
            }

            pi.CreateTarget(device_tpm);
            IList<Test> tests_tpm = project.GetTests();
            if (tests_tpm.Count == 0)
            {
                Log("Warning! Device Level Test list count is 0");
                Console.ReadLine();
                return tests_tpm;
            }
            Test_List = tests_tpm;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception :- {0}", e.ToString());
        }
        return Test_List;
    }

    //apply filters
    public static PlaylistManager ApplyPlaylist(Project projectname, string playlistpath)
    {
        PlaylistManager pl_manager = null;
        try
        {
            pl_manager = new PlaylistManager(projectname);
            if (pl_manager == null)
            {
                Log(String.Format("Cannot make playlist manager for the project:- {0}", projectname.Name.ToString()));
            }
            if(pl_manager.IsPlaylistLoaded() == true)
            {
                Log("Playlist loaded.. unloading ");
                pl_manager.UnloadPlaylist();
                if (pl_manager.IsPlaylistLoaded() == false)
                { 
                    Log("Unloaded successfully");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (File.Exists(playlistpath))
                {
                    pl_manager.LoadPlaylist(playlistpath);
                    if (pl_manager.IsPlaylistLoaded() == false)
                    {
                        Log("Error in applying playlist:- " + playlistpath);
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        Log("Loaded playlist:- " + playlistpath);
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    Log(String.Format("ERROR!Playlist file {0} not found!", playlistpath));
                    return pl_manager;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception:-{0}", e.ToString());
        }

        return pl_manager;
    }

    //load pl
    public static IList<Test> LoadPlaylist(Project project, string playlistpath)
    {
        IList<Test> test_list = null;
        try
        {                
            PlaylistManager pl_manager = new PlaylistManager(project);
            pl_manager.LoadPlaylist(playlistpath);
            if (pl_manager.IsPlaylistLoaded() == true)
            {
                Log(String.Format("Playlist loaded:- {0}", playlistpath));
            }
            else
            {
                Log("Error loading playlist");
            }
            test_list = project.GetTests();
            Log(String.Format("{0} tests found", test_list.Count.ToString()));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception:-{0}", e.ToString());
        }
        return test_list;
    }



    //run tests
    public static List<string> RunTests(Project project, IList<Test> test_list, int iID)
    {
        List<int> result = new List<int> { };
        List<string> Results = new List<string> { };

        try
        {                              
            IList<TestResult> res_list = null;
            double time = 0;
            List<Test> test_tpm=new List<Test> { };

            //system level
            if (iID == 1)
            {
                foreach (Test t in test_list)
                {
                    if (t.Name.ToLower().Contains("tpm 2.0") && !t.Name.ToLower().Contains("interface 1.3 test"))
                    {
                        test_tpm.Add(t);
                    }
                }
            }
            //device level
            if (iID == 2)
            {
                foreach (Test t in test_list)
                {
                    if (t.Name.ToLower().Contains("tpm"))
                    {
                        test_tpm.Add(t);
                    }
                }

            }


            //get total time
            foreach (Test t in test_tpm)
            {
                time += t.EstimatedRuntime.TotalSeconds;
            }

            Log(string.Format("Total test time:- {0}", time.ToString()));

            foreach (Test t in test_tpm)
            {          
                res_list = t.QueueTest();
                Log(string.Format("Queued test:-{0}", t.Name.ToString()));
            }

            while (project.Info.Status == ProjectStatus.Running)
            {
                if(project.Info.Status == ProjectStatus.NotRunning)
                {
                    break;
                }
                Log(string.Format("Running count:-{0}", project.Info.RunningCount.ToString()));    
                Log(string.Format("Waiting for {0} secs", time.ToString()));
                Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(time) * 1000);   //millisec  
                Log(string.Format("{0} secs elapsed", time.ToString()));
                Log(string.Format("Running count:-{0}", project.Info.RunningCount.ToString()));
            }

            //check results
            Log(string.Format("Passed count:-{0}", project.Info.PassedCount.ToString()));
            Log(string.Format("Failed count:-{0}", project.Info.FailedCount.ToString()));

            foreach(Test t in test_tpm)
            {
                Results.Add(ProcessTest(t));
            }

            //PackageWriter package = new PackageWriter(project);
            //package.Save(sPackageName);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception:- {0}", e.ToString());
        }
        return Results;
    }

    //process a test result
    public static string ProcessTest(Test test)
    {
        string sOutput = null;
        try
        {
            foreach (var result in test.GetTestResults())
            {
                string sTestTargetDevice = string.Join("; ", from a in test.GetTestTargets()
                                                            select a.Name);

                Log("Test: " + test.Name);
                sOutput+=(String.Format("TestCase:-{0}\n", test.Name));
                Log("Target: " + sTestTargetDevice);
                sOutput+=(String.Format("Target:-{0}\n", sTestTargetDevice));
                Log("Test Result: " + test.Status.ToString());
                sOutput+=(String.Format("Test Result:- {0}\n",test.Status.ToString() ));
                Log("RunTime (min): " + System.Math.Round((result.CompletionTime - result.StartTime).TotalMinutes));
                sOutput+=(String.Format("Runtime:-{0}\n", System.Math.Round((result.CompletionTime - result.StartTime).TotalMinutes)));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception:-{0}",e.Message);
        }
        return sOutput;
    }

    //Log into log file
    public static void Log(string sMsg)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sMsg);
            File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(sExePath,sLogFile), sMsg + "\n");                
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception:-{0}", e.Message);
        }
    }

    //MAIN
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {                          
        try
        {
            string controllerName = "HLK-RS3";
            string projectName = null, TargetName = null, TestPoolName = null;

            if (args.Length != 3)   //syntax
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid arguments:-\nSyntax:-\nHLKAutomation.exe TargetName projectName TestPoolName");
                return;
            }

            TargetName = args[0];
            projectName = args[1];
            TestPoolName = args[2];

            string sExePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            string playlistpath = Path.Combine(sExePath, "playlist.xml");
            List<int> PassFailCount = new List<int> { };
            List<string> Results = new List<string> { };

            if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(sExePath, sLogFile)))     //delete log file if exist
            {
                File.Delete(Path.Combine(sExePath, sLogFile));
            }

            ProjectManager manager = ConnectToController(controllerName);   //connect to controller
            Project project = CreateProject(manager, projectName);     //create project if not exist  
            MachinePool testpool = CreatePool(manager, TestPoolName);   //create test pool                
            Machine TargetMachine = LookForMachine(manager, TargetName, testpool);    //check if test machine is there in test pool or not, if in default, move to test pool                

            if (TargetMachine != null)   //if system is valid
            {
                PrepareTargetMachine(TargetMachine);   //now make it ready  
                IList<Test> test_list = GetTestsDeviceLevel(TargetMachine, testpool, project);  //get list of tests
                Console.WriteLine("{0} tests found", test_list.Count.ToString());                    
                test_list = LoadPlaylist(project, playlistpath);    //load playlist
                Results = RunTests(project, test_list, 2);          //run filtered tests          
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            else
            {                   
                Console.WriteLine("Error! Machine is N/A");
                Console.ReadLine();                    
            }    

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception in main:- {0}", e.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

}